# Magnolia CMS doesn't recognise my light-module .jar file

Tags: magnolia

When I run my Magnolia instance and open Pages, I'm seeing this message:

[image: magnolia pages app error]

But I have my light-modules added:

[image: light-module files]

And also the path in magnolia.properties file is pointing to my .jar file folder

> magnolia.resources.dir=${magnolia.home}/WEB-INF/lib

This is my structure in the attachment:

[image: file structure]

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't find what. If my question is not described enough, let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @rainxart - light modules are Magnolia modules created with a variety of text files (and jar files shouldn't be involved.)

Comment: Hi @Zak here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Resources and here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/Installing+a+module#Installingamodule-JARfiles you can see how you can use .jar file. Maybe I understood something wrong, but I read that you can make you light-module folder into .jar file and import it like module in your blossom instance.

Answer (score 1):

magnolia.resources.dir is the correct place to put them however, jars are not considered as light modules. For more information about how to define a light module have a look at [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Light+modules).

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. I tired to change it to standard light module folder and still have the same error. 
If I put the .jar or point to a folder file into magnolia instance installed with "mgnl jumpstart" is working fine, but when I tried to set it into blossom installation I'm receiving this error.

Comment: Do you create a jar out of your light module?

Comment: Yes, I'm making a jar out of my light module.

Comment: Can you see those files from resources files app? Can you also try to put your folder (light-module) directly to magnolia.resources.dir?